# how could I recognize an email as auto-forward email?

Tags: email, mime

I have a task which needs me to find out the auto-forward email from an email set.
Originally I recoginize an email whose sender contains "caf_|auto_" and "+" and "_" as auto-forward email,for example "test3128+caf_=test3128=yahoo.com@gmail.com".
But finallly I find that the above-mentioned feature is not always right.Because the email may be an auto-forward or an auto-reply email.
Could anyone give me any help?You have my thanks.

Comment: Are you talking specifically about Gmail?

Comment: no,I am talking about general email,not specific kind of email.Thanks.

Comment: There's just no standard related to that. Gmail offers those tricks as a custom service, other providers will normally not.